# ListView with Vertical Gridlines and Background Color

Tags: wpf, listview, gridlines

I've got a WPF ListView with vertical lines using the following style:  (sorry for the length, but i thought i should include it)

```
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="verticalLineColor" Color="Red" />
    <Style x:Key="{x:Static GridView.GridViewScrollViewerStyleKey}" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                    <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <DockPanel Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <ScrollViewer Focusable="false" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                                <GridViewHeaderRowPresenter x:Name="viewHeaderRowPresenter"
                                        Margin="-2,0,-2,0"
                                        Columns="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.Columns, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                        ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                        ColumnHeaderTemplate="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderTemplate, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                        ColumnHeaderTemplateSelector="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderTemplateSelector, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                        AllowsColumnReorder="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.AllowsColumnReorder, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                        ColumnHeaderContextMenu="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderContextMenu, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                        ColumnHeaderToolTip="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderToolTip, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                        SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />


                            </ScrollViewer>

                            <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter"
                                        SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"                                         
                                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                        KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Local"
                                        CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}">

                                <ScrollContentPresenter.Content>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <!-- Container of vertical and horizontal lines -->
                                        <ItemsControl Margin="-1,0,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.Columns, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                    <Border Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth}" BorderThickness="0,0,.5,0" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource verticalLineColor}" Opacity="1" />
                                                </DataTemplate>
                                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                        </ItemsControl>
                                        <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </ScrollContentPresenter.Content>
                            </ScrollContentPresenter>
                        </DockPanel>
                        <ScrollBar Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" Cursor="Arrow" x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" Grid.Row="1" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}" Minimum="0.0" Value="{Binding Path=HorizontalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Orientation="Horizontal" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"/>
                        <ScrollBar Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" Cursor="Arrow" x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" Grid.Column="1" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}" Minimum="0.0" Value="{Binding Path=VerticalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Orientation="Vertical" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"/>
                        <DockPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Background="{Binding Path=Background, ElementName=PART_VerticalScrollBar}" LastChildFill="false">
                            <Rectangle Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" Width="1" Fill="White" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
                            <Rectangle Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" Height="1" Fill="White" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Now, everything works great here.  The issue I'm now running into is that I need to shade one of the ListView rows if one of my fields is 0.  I've got the following code which gets me 90% of the way there:

```
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,-2,0,-1"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding QtyInBox}" Value="0">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Now, the problem I'm running into is that when I set the background, it appears to "overwrite" the grid lines.  [image]

Is there any way to get those vertical lines to show through?

EDIT #1:  OK, so after playing around for a bit, I'm wondering if this might work; In the following section of code:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Border Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth}" BorderThickness="0,0,.5,0" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource verticalLineColor}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

If I can somehow hook into the `Background` property there, I should be able to get this working.  Can anybody point me in the right direction for binding here?  The field I'd need to bind to is `QtyInBox` on the `ItemSource` of the ListView.

EDIT #2:  Looks like I was wrong there; that seems to be binding the entire column; so I can't set the background of just one row there.  Back to the drawing board...

Comment: ask far as I can see the lines are the same color as background, what happens if you use a different color?

Comment: Yeah; i just noticed that.  It's a subtle difference (LightGray vs Gray).  I'll change that to red to make it more apparent

Comment: Just by looking at it I suppose the issue may be caused by the negative left and right marging you've set. Try to set the `Margin` in `ItemContainerStyle` to *0* (or even *"0,-1,0,-1"*) and see if it helps.

Comment: Lucas, good advice, but no dice.  The margins are tweaked to prevent whitespace in between the listview rows when shading.  If i take those margins out, i get the whitespace in there, and can see the vertical line.  It definitely seems like the background property is "writing on top of" the vertical lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I wasn't able to figure out a true solution to this.

Best I could do was to set the transparency of the background to something like .6 or .7.

Wasn't a perfect solution; as it caused the text to be a little blurry, but it was good enough for now.